# 301 redirect from www.example.com to http://example.com in apache htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to redirect www.example.com to example.com via htaccess while on zend framework](https://serverfault.com/questions/225974/how-to-redirect-www-example-com-to-example-com-via-htaccess-while-on-zend-framewo)

I want to redirect

```
www.example.com to example.com
```

Can any body help me, How can do that using htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ 
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```